# Laravel Query Builder - problema com dois join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, querybuilder

Atualmente tenho a uma query que pega os posts e busca por meio de join alguns dados do usuário

```
$posts = \App\Post::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.author_id')
  ->select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.excerpt', 'posts.slug', 'posts.created_at', 'posts.image', 'users.avatar', 'users.name', 'users.username')
  ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
  ->paginate(14);
```

Implementei recentemente um sistema de like simples, estilo facebook e gostaria de adicionar na mesma query o somatório de likes de acordo com o post

Tentei adicionar o like na mesma query da seguinte forma

```
$posts = \App\Post::join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.author_id')
  ->join('likes', 'posts.id', '=', 'likes.post_id')
  ->select('posts.id', 'posts.title', 'posts.excerpt', 'posts.slug', 'posts.created_at', 'posts.image', 'users.avatar', 'users.name', 'users.username', DB::raw('count(likes.post_id) as likeCount'))
  ->groupBy('likes.id')
  ->orderBy('posts.created_at', 'desc')
  ->paginate(14);
```

Como poderia resolver a query ?
O join resolve ou é melhor um outro método.

Answer (score 0):

O Join resolve, mas podes simplificar criando relações entre entre os modelos.

Exemplo:
No modelo Post adicionas o seguinte (Isto é exemplificativo):

```
public function user()
{
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}



public function likes()
{
      return $this->hasMany('App\Likes', 'post_id');
}
```

Depois na query basta fazeres:

```
\App\Post::with('user','likes')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(14);
```

Podes ler um pouco mais sobre isso aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships